# O que fazer quando criador da pergunta resolveu sua dúvida/problema mas não posta como resposta?

Tags: debate

Olhando esta pergunta: [Como recuperar dados de uma consulta feita com objeto "ADODB.Command"?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/48130/como-recuperar-dados-de-uma-consulta-feita-com-objeto-adodb-command) reparei que quem fez a pergunta comentou que resolveu o problema e inclusive colocou a resposta no comentário.

O @Caputo comentou a ele para que adicione a solução como resposta mas ainda não foi feito. Como devemos proceder nestes casos? É uma boa ideia responder no lugar dele e citá-lo ou temos outras alternativas?

Comment: Pergunta relacionada: [Por que muitas pessoas respondem nos comentários em vez de criar uma resposta?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2333/18327)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Algumas pessoas podem não gostar disto mas o que importa aqui é a comunidade. É o bem maior. Nos interessa que as perguntas tenham respostas.

Ele teve a oportunidade de postar como resposta. Não fez. Faça você.

Seria elegante marcar a resposta como Community Wiki para deixar claro que ela não é de sua autoria, que você está fazendo pelo bem da comunidade e qualquer um (com um reputação mínima) pode ir lá e melhorar. O autor do comentário, pode melhorar. Esta atitude evita a ideia de que só colocou a resposta que provavelmente, por meios próprios, nem sabe se está certa para ganhar pontos ilegítimos.

Comment: Havia esquecido da opção de marcar como Community Wiki, bem lembrado amigo.

Comment: Perfeitamente. Só é importante lembrar de dar um tempo pra quem escreveu a pergunta ter tempo de fazer a resposta. A comunidade funciona de maneira assíncrona, e nem sempre a pessoa vai estar disponível na hora que for recomendado que escreva uma resposta.