# Pergunta resolvida pelo comentário, mas sem saber como

Tags: suporte

Tem a seguinte pergunta no SOpt:
[Android - É possivel reproduzir vídeos em uma WebView?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/294927/android-%C3%89-possivel-reproduzir-v%C3%ADdeos-em-uma-webview?noredirect=1#comment599800_294927)

Colei um [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10309353/android-webview-not-playing-video) que resolveu o problema do usuário, mas no link não explica o porque dos passos utilizados.

Copio a solução e colo (como fiz, pois já vi em outros tópicos), mesmo sem saber o que foi feito, ou deixo em aberto, sem colocar nada ?

Comment: Relacionado: [Por que muitas pessoas respondem nos comentários em vez de criar uma resposta?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2333/por-que-muitas-pessoas-respondem-nos-comentários-em-vez-de-criar-uma-resposta/2334#2334)

Comment: Relacionado: [O que fazer quando criador da pergunta resolveu sua dúvida/problema mas não posta como resposta?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2420/o-que-fazer-quando-criador-da-pergunta-resolveu-sua-dúvida-problema-mas-não-post?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: @Articuno gostei dessa 2a, acho que entra mais no caso. O código está lá, foi testado e resolveu, e serve para outras pessoas. Mas não tem detalhadamente o porque, então quem irá ver, pode até entender, como alguém que também não. Então seria legal postar (para não deixar somente um link) e colocar o `Community Wiki` ?

Comment: Nao ha problema algum o que voce fez, desde que de os devidos creditos linkando a fonte de onde voce tirou o codigo. Eu ja respondi perguntas onde so vi o codigo no SOEn sem entender, mas depois corri atras pra entender melhor e poder explicar, [essa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/140724/28595) é um exemplo, na original o cara nao entra em detalhes, mas eu procurei entender o codigo e reproduzi ele com varios comentarios explicativos.

Comment: Então, é exatamente o que eu queria fazer, mas precisa de tempo. Só que, nesse meio tempo, vem, chega um cara, entra no link, copia e cola, aí a pergunta fica como resolvida da mesma forma. Prefiro então eu responder, pois as vezes eu dou uma revisadas nas minhas respostas porque sei que queria mexer, ou até para melhorar algumas mais antigas, por enriquecer mais o conteúdo, ou até por ter descoberto algo melhor !

Comment: Concordo com o Articuno, e acho que é util colocar como resposta nesses casos, mas deve ser acompanhado de explicação caso o original não tenha. É sempre util tentar evitar o efeito copy paste cego

Comment: Eu acho esquisito postar apenas o código sem nenhuma explicação. Se vc se engajou no assunto, pode até não ter entendido oq o código faz, mas alguma coisa vc deveria saber e postar algum texto explicando, pelo menos parcialmente, o que o código faz. Porque isso fica parecendo que vc está interessado apenas em ganhar os pontos. Mas de todo não é errado, só acho um pouco "cafajeste" rss

Comment: @dvd é, o que mais vai parecer é isso ! rs Eu tento sempre pensar o que pode acontecer, qual a melhor forma para deixar um histórico sem também que alguém vá e faça o copy&paste, e depois não se interesse me voltar e melhorar.