# Pergunta respondida no comentário

Tags: debate

Existem algumas perguntas aqui no *meta* para o que fazer quando uma pergunta é respondida via comentário, como [esta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2420/o-que-fazer-quando-criador-da-pergunta-resolveu-sua-d%C3%BAvida-problema-mas-n%C3%A3o-post), por exemplo.

Minha dúvida é o que fazer com a pergunta quando o comentário ajuda ao autor a encontrar a solução, como [nesse caso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/304223/formato-de-data-errado?noredirect=1#comment617560_304223).

A pergunta deve ser fechada? O autor/alguém deve responder a pergunta?

Entendo que idealmente todas as perguntas devem ser marcadas como respondida para auxiliar quem vem em busca de uma solução para um problema semelhante, e acredito que no caso da pergunta que referenciei ela precise de uma resposta.

Comment: @Renan não sei se vai concordar mas no caso específico que citei, não teria como transformar o comentário em uma resposta, pois não havia código; por isso não consegui "encaixar" meu motivo em um dos listados na resposta da pergunta que você sugere como duplicata..

Comment: Posso estar enganado, mas bem antigamente o SO permitia marcar um comentário como resposta. Inúmeras vezes já encontrei perguntas, sem resposta, no qual algum comentário na pergunta era o suficiente para respondê-la de forma satisfatória. Não lembro exatamente se era por meio de `flag` ou se era uma opção que aparecia em cada comentário, exclusiva para isto.

Answer (score -2):

Me antecipando a respostas,

comentei para que o autor alterasse a pergunta para adicionar o código que ele identificou como errado (com base no comentário) e respondesse à própria pergunta, para que não ficasse em aberto/sem resposta.

Preferi esta *"solução"* à sugerir que a pergunta fosse fechada.